# How to setup a 802.11ac hotspot with NetworkManager

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, hotspot, networkmanager

Running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265. I've been trying to setup a 5Ghz ac hotspot to tether my wired connection, but I can't get the hotspot to use 802.11ac.

I've set the regulatory region to US with `iw reg set` and with the following NetworkManager profile loaded:

```
[connection]
id=Marcus Secured
uuid=ca2368eb-0013-47e5-ab74-0f313f9e1637
type=wifi
interface-name=wlan0
permissions=
timestamp=1557925975

[wifi]
band=a
channel=165
mac-address=<MAC ADDR>
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=ap
seen-bssids=<BSSID>;
ssid=Marcus Secured

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=<Hotspot Password>

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=shared

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
ip6-privacy=0
method=shared
```

When I connect to the Hotspot from my Mac, it shows that the wifi is connected to a 5Ghz channel but its not using 802.11ac.

```
Current Network Information:
  Marcus Secured:
    PHY Mode:   802.11n
    BSSID:  <BSSID>
    Channel:    165
    Country Code:   US
    Network Type:   Infrastructure
    Security:   WPA/WPA2 Personal
    Signal / Noise: -42 dBm / -96 dBm
    Transmit Rate:  145
    MCS Index:  15
```

Comment: What model Mac? What's the model of the wifi adapter in the Mac?

Comment: I don't think my Mac is the one to blame, since the PHY mode is determined and broadcasted by the access point. But FYI its a MacBookPro14,2 with BCM43xx (I believe its BCM4360).

Comment: That is a common misconception, the PHY rates are advertised through the SSID beacon. The card connects with the fastest speed it can negotiate, but can/will gracefully fallback to the lower rates advertised for many reasons. (Interference, buggy drivers, a bad antenna connection, etc). This sounds like the drivers in Ubuntu honestly. I have only done this through hostapd in Ubuntu which has the configuration variable "**hw_mode=**". You may want to try alternative drivers for the card or use hostapd to force it to use a newer 802.11 standard.